# I want to rename part of the file names

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have multiple files inside multiple sub folders like below :

```
C:\Folder1\ABCndsnoids.txt
C:\Folder1\ABCkfdsf.txt
C:\Folder1\ABCdds.txt
C:\Folder2\ABCkjnfjdfds.txt
C:\Folder2\ABCanmdlkmdsa.txt
C:\Folder3\ABCinvdsjoivdsjvds.txt
C:\Folder3\ABCnfdsnds.txt
```

So every file starts with ABC but have different characters after that. Now I want ABC to be replaced with EFGHI without changing any other character.

I used the following cmd but it replaced the 4th and 5th character of the file name.

```
for /R %x in (ABC*) do ren "%x" EFGHI*
```

Example:

```
C:\Folder3\**ABC12345**.txt was replaced to C:\Folder3\**EFGHI345**.txt
```

I dont want the 4th and 5th characted to be replaced.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want. Remove the `ECHO` after you've verified it.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /R %%x IN (ABC*) DO (
  SET OLD=%%~nxx
  SET NEW=EFGHI!OLD:~3!
  ECHO REN "!OLD!" "!NEW!"
)
```

Comment: do you really need `.txt` when you use `%%~nx`?

Comment: @Stephan Yes because `%%~nx` only gets the file name, and does not include the extension.

Comment: argh - i should read more carefully. Wouldn't it be better to use `%%~nxx` then instead of adding `.txt` manually?

Comment: @Stephan Yes, it would be better...I wasn't thinking clearly, thanks for the tip. :) I fixed my code.

Comment: Thanks Aphoria! Let me test it.